# Embed AngularJS Page in Ember Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ember.js

There is one massive Ember Application which is running. 
Now I want to embed AngularJS feature in Ember Context.
**OnClick of a button in EmberJS, AngularJS feature(HTML Page) has to open as New Tab in Ember Page or Dialog box.**
I tried to see what are different ways how we can embed AngularJS page in Ember. 
Please let me know if there is way by which AngularJS Page can be embedded in Ember.

Comment: I know you can do this with ember components by using [ember-islands](https://github.com/mitchlloyd/ember-islands) look for a similar lib for the angular ecosystem

Comment: I have a similar application where Angular App needs to be embed with Ember. Did you find any solution for this. ?

I created an Ember component and bootstrapped the angular app , but somehow i am getting a call stack error from the angular library. I think some variables are conflicting and hence going for an infinite recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

I think is very bad idea to include a js framework into another. It's like including php into JS SPA framework (ember, angular...) or whatever else...
If you want to use AngularJS, you should think about migrating from ember to angular.

Comment: The AngularJS feature is part of One AngularJS application.Going ahead this feature will be used by other applications. So there should be any workaround.

Comment: Yes but I don't know how can you put an AngularJS feature into your Ember application without declaring a new Angular module (an application)... So you will have two frameworks...